# Continuity in Metric Spaces between two spaces under a function f

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Let (X,d) and (Y,e) be metric spaces , and let f:X→Y be a function. Explain but do not prove if the statement is correct.

If there exists r>0 so that $e((f(x1),f(x2))$$≤$  $r(d(x1,x2))$for every $x_1,x_2$∈X , then f is continuous. Does the converse hold?

I am having difficulty getting around this question. I have a feeling that it doesnt hold but the converse does, using the "ϵ−δ" definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sean, the statement is true, and its converse is not. Functions which satisfy
$$
e(f(x),f(y))\leq r d(x,y),\qquad x,y\in X
$$
are called Lipschitz continuous, and they are indeed continuous, which is easily proven by using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition. But you can "see" this directly: Continuity means that if you have two points $x$ and $y$ close to each other (i.e. $d(x,y)$ is small), then their images $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have to be close to each other, too (i.e. $e(f(x),f(y))$ is small). But because of the above relation this is clear, since if the right hand sight is small, so has to be the left hand side.

The converse, however, is not true. Consider $X=Y=\mathbb R$, $e=d=|\cdot|$, and $f(x)=x^2$. If $f$ were Lipschitz continuous, then we had $|f(x)-f(y)|=|x^2-y^2|=|x-y||x+y|\leq r|x-y|$, which implied $|x+y|\leq r$ for each $x,y\in\mathbb R$. But $|x+y|$ can get arbitrarily large, which is a contradiction.